# What's the equivalent to loadNibNamed in Swift

Tags: swift

I am converting my Objective-C code to Swift and was wondering what is the swift equivalent to this code

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Games-New" owner:nil  
options:nil] firstObject];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't wonder about individual methods -- they all follow the same conversion rules. If you're converting your code to swift, you should be familiar with [how to call Objective-C methods from Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Games-New", owner: nil, options: nil)[0]
```

Comment: This gives me a `'Bool' does not have a member named 'subscript'` compile error.

Comment: For me, Xcode 6 Beta 5 nagged about the "options", which it stated should be "topLevelObjects".

Comment: I get an error when trying this: Type 'AnyObject' cannot be implicitly downcasts to 'UIView';did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast? I don't want to use 'as UIView' at the end...

Comment: @speg I don't think the [0] at the end should be there. Trying to get mine working too but that subscript part doesn't look right either way...

Comment: You need to cast it, loadNibNamed returns [AnyObject]

```var awesomeView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Games-New", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? AwesomeView```

Comment: I don't know about previous versions, but in Swift 2 it looks like:   let cell: UITableViewCell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(cellIdentifier, owner:self, options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell

Comment: `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Games-New", owner: nil, options: nil).firstObject` without hardcoding

Comment: This doesn't compile in Swift 3

Comment: in Swift 4, NSBundle.mainBundle changed to Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyDenizbankLoading", owner: nil, options: nil)![0]

Answer (score 35):

Maybe the API has changed. The third parameter of `loadNibNamed` is no longer `options`, it's `topLevelObjects`. The following code works for me:

```
var objects: NSArray?
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &objects)
```

Comment: For OS X 10.10, this is more correct than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: FWIW, when I try this I get the following syntax error: `value of optional type 'NSArray?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`. Instead of declaring `objects` to be an optional value, it seems that you should initialize it with an empty `NSArray()`.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a UIView extension

```
public extension UIView {

    public class func instantiateFromNib<T: UIView>(viewType: T.Type) -> T {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(String(describing: viewType), owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! T
    }

    public class func instantiateFromNib() -> Self {
        return instantiateFromNib(self)
    }

}
```

Usage

```
let awesomeView = AwesomeView.instantiateFromNib()
```

OR

```
let awesomeView = UIView.instantiateFromNib(AwesomeView.self)
```

Comment: This is causing crash for me

Comment: are you not missing some optionals? `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(String(viewType), owner: nil, options: nil).first as? T`, `func instantiateFromNib<T: UIView>(viewType: T.Type) -> T?`, `public class func instantiateFromNib() -> Self?`

Comment: @HuguesBR I don't see why it should use optionals

Comment: @aryaxt or the force unwrap, you've added :)

Comment: oooh gotcha, I posted this answer when swift 1.0 was out which allowed `as` :)

Comment: Why do we have to do `.first`? what's the need for it? Doesn't the nib contain a view only?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

---

**name**
The name of the nib file, which need not include the .nib extension.

**owner**
The object to assign as the nib’s File's Owner object.

**options** 
A dictionary containing the options to use when opening the nib file.

**first**
if you do not define first then grabing all view .. so you need to grab one view inside that  set `frist` .

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourUIView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! yourUIView
```

Comment: what do you mean it would grab all views? How can there possibly be multiple views?! I only drag one view from the storyboard and then put a label/image inside of it and am done. Or does this mean I can drag multiple *container*-like views and the first view I drag out would be the first or something? <-- that would be a pretty bad idea, I mean simply because which one I dragged out first...though I doubt that's what it means...

Comment: if i have one or more view . then grab all view so i need to be the first view  to load .  it's a little cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Use this to load your nib.

```
let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView
```

Then you can add it to your view as you normally would.

```
view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: NSBundle' has been renamed to 'Bundle. Please update your code block.    let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyDenizbankLoading", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! UIView

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3:

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Games-New", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0]
```

FYI: NS is (not entirely) removed in Swift 3

Answer (score 3):

In the docs, it looks like it is different for [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1402909-loadnibnamed) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1618147-loadnibnamed).

For **macOS** and **Swift 4**, the following worked for me:

```
func loadFromNib(_ nibName: String) -> NSView? {
    var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
    if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: nibName), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
        return topLevelObjects?.first(where: { $0 is NSView } ) as? NSView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 4, **NSBundle.mainBundle** changed to **Bundle.main.loadNibNamed**

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyDenizbankLoading", owner: nil, options: nil)![0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    var objects: NSArray?
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CellView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &objects)

    var newView = NSView()
    for object in objects ?? [] {
        if (object is NSView) {
            newView = object as! NSView
            break;
        }
    }

    var cellView: CellView?
    for view in newView.subviews {
        print("class: \(view.className) ")
        if (view is CellView) {
            cellView = view as? CellView
            break;
        }
    }

    cellView?.imageView.image = image
    cellView?.textFieldView.stringValue = text

    return cellView
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how to do in macOS in Swift 4

**Register**

```
collectionView.register(NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "Cell"), bundle: nil)!,
                            forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"))
```

**Dequeue**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

  let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"), for: indexPath)
  guard let cell = item as? Cell else { return item }

  let value = values[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
  cell.imageView?.setImage(url: value, placeholder: Image(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "placeholder")))

  return cell
 }
```